# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set. How to get data from clipboard in linux with java?

Tags: java

I try to get data from the clipboard and try to use follow code:

```
public static String getValueFromClipboard() {
      Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); // {1}
    try {
      return (String) c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (Exception e){
      throw new RuntimeException("An error was occurs while clipboard parsing. " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This code works well when I launch the project on Windows, but when the project executes on the server (CentOS/Fedora) I get the following error:

```
 No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

This error occurs on the line `{1}`:

```
Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
```

How to correctly get the data from the clipboard with Linux?

Comment: Most "servers" don't have any graphical UI running, therefore no X11. That means there *is* no clipboard. What clipboard do you expect to capture when you try to get the clipboard content on the server?

Comment: @JoachimSauer This is a project for web testing. The data should be set to the clipboard from the website (with a button clicking). I suppose the graphical UI is supported since the graphical screenshots are present in the allure-reports

Comment: @JoachimSauer needs to add - tests running in the docker image. But anyway - UI is existed there (as I understand).

Comment: If this is about web applications then `Toolkit` is missing the point: it's trying to access the clipboard **one the server** whereas your application (more correctly: your webapp/JavaScript) probably needs to access the **clients** clipboard.

Comment: @JoachimSauer in other words - this task is impossible?

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly your requirements are, but I guess `Toolkit` is the wrong tool for the job. If you want to verify that the browser copied something to the clipboard, you might have to use browser-related tools (possibly JavaScript, maybe some development API) to verify that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer do you mean I can try to get data from the clipboard with JS? But not with Java?